# How can i have a property in the compile group gradle file

Tags: maven, grails, gradle, deployment, ant

Hi I want to use a gradle property in my gradle build file like this:

compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '${hibernateVersion}'

and i have in the gradle.properties this entry
hibernateVersion:5.2.6.Final

But each time it gives me error:

```
 Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency_Decorated
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `"${hibernateVerison}"` instead of `'${hibernateVersion}'`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:$hibernateVersion"
```